# Post data from one form to 2 different url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, forms

How i can send post from one form to 2 different url

Like send POST name to process.php and confirm.php in the same times

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(),     function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});`
```

And my form

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="confirm.php" method="POST"> 

<label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
<br>
<label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>  
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/> 
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You can only do that, if you cancel the normal submit of the form, and makes both those requests via AJAX. But anyway, in most cases where people ask something like this, they are on the wrong track already – so please describe what you actually want to _achieve_ here first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understood, you want to send the input name value from your form to two different PHP files at once?
You can do this by using jquery:

Give an ID to submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="send" value="Submit"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
     //When the user click on Submit, the post starts

     $("#send").click(function(){
     //get the input field name value
     var vNAME = $("#name").val();

     //send it first to process.php
     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "process.php",
      data: {name: vNAME},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          //if process.php receive the post data and process right, it returns
          //a message of success otherwise, return a error message.
          if(data.success=="true"){
             ... successful message! 
          }else{
             ... unsuccessful message! 
          }              
      }
     });

     //sending to confirm.php
     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "confirm.php",
      data: {name: vNAME},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          //if process.php receive the post data and process right, it returns
          //a message of success otherwise, return a error message.
          if(data.success=="true"){
             ... successful message! 
          }else{
             ... unsuccessful message! 
          }              
      }
     });
  });
});
```